# Использование Прокси в pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telegram

Всех приветствую,хотел создать бота для телеграмма,но он не подключается к сети.Полазив по англостаку нашёл способ с использовании проксей,но делая всё по инструкции ничего не хочет подключаться.Все зависимости установлены.Мой вопрос просвящался уже здесь:https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/pull/494/commits/10ec897fb541d1197c39ac6cc2fa7923041e2075 (автор ридми пишет что работает 100%).
Я пробовал в этой строчку

> apihelper.proxy = {'http', 'http://10.10.1.10:3128'}
>   менять адрес и порт,но всё безрезультатно.При запуске кода выводит следующее:

```
2018-04-26 17:22:06,626 (util.py:65 PollingThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "AttributeError occurred, args=("'set' object has no attribute 'get'",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Di\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 59, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Di\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 159, in __retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Di\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 129, in get_updates
    json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "C:\Users\Di\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 175, in get_updates
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
  File "C:\Users\Di\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 54, in _make_request
    timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), proxies=proxy)
  File "C:\Users\Di\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Di\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Di\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 337, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "C:\Users\Di\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 241, in get_connection
    proxy = proxies.get(urlparse(url.lower()).scheme)
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'get'
"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Di/Desktop/anbot/tgtimed/main.py", line 15, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "C:\Users\Di\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 264, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Di\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 287, in __threaded_polling
    polling_thread.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\Di\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 78, in raise_exceptions
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
  File "C:\Users\Di\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Di\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 59, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Di\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 159, in __retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Di\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 129, in get_updates
    json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "C:\Users\Di\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 175, in get_updates
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
  File "C:\Users\Di\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 54, in _make_request
    timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), proxies=proxy)
  File "C:\Users\Di\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Di\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Di\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 337, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "C:\Users\Di\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 241, in get_connection
    proxy = proxies.get(urlparse(url.lower()).scheme)
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: попробуйте так `apihelper.proxy = {'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:3128'}`, т.к. traceback указывает на то что объект proxy - должен иметь метод get которого нет у множества, но есть у словарей.

Comment: @godva,я скопипастил то что вы предложили,но особой разницы не увидел.

Answer (score 1):

У меня аналогичная проблема. Пытался пустить через сокс5 через тор, рабочие прокси из других стран, но ничего, постоянно выдает такую ошибку.

```
    2018-04-27 23:13:25,315 (util.py:65 PollingThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "ConnectionError occurred, args=(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer')),)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 850, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 326, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 329, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 814, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1068, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 357, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 850, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 326, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 329, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 814, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1068, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 59, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 159, in __retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 129, in get_updates
    json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 175, in get_updates
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 54, in _make_request
    timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), proxies=proxy)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 490, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))
"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 850, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 326, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 329, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 814, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1068, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 357, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 850, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 326, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 329, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 814, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1068, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/main.py", line 678, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 264, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 287, in __threaded_polling
    polling_thread.raise_exceptions()
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 78, in raise_exceptions
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 59, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 159, in __retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 129, in get_updates
    json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 175, in get_updates
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 54, in _make_request
    timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), proxies=proxy)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sviperm/Documents/PycharmProjects/MyPasswordsBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 490, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Нашел два решения:

1. Пустить весь трафик через впн (можно тунельного медведя, но там всего 500 мб + 1 гб за публикацию в твиттер), мало, согласен.
2. Второй вариант это пустить весь трафик на роутере через ip6v, это чуть сложнее и не у всех роутеров, НО это и обходит любые блокировки, даже звоник будут в тг работать.